# Offline static content in React app

Tags: reactjs, offline

I have a react app created with create-react-app. I would like to add an image not part of the react app to the offline manifest. The image is just referenced from index.html. I don't understand how I can include this in the offline manifest.

The react app is ejected.

Answer (score -1):

Put the image in the public folder just as in a regular website and refer to that image. Everything in the src folder is put in a big js file after building so you cant use that

Comment: That's what I've done, but it doesn't get included in the offline manifest and doesn't get a unique filename suffix either.